# How to identify a users name from their ID?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

If I have a list of IDs, how do I identify the usernames from the the IDs? So I can get the bot to be able to say who the IDs are and put that in a message?

Comment: Please give more detail, and some code too.

Comment: If I have a list of IDs such as `blacklist = ["283068026960609283"]`, how can I identify the IDs username?

Comment: Ok, I understand. You should look through the `discordpy` docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this function which returns a user object.

`user = await bot.get_user_info("user id here")`

Then you can do, `user.name` which returns the username.

Hopefully this works!